# Why are there two different XIAOMI Stocks?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, markets, isin

I'd like to buy Xiaomi Stocks. When I search in my Brokers List, i find two different Stocks:

ISIN:US98421U1088 Symb: 3CPA
&
ISIN:KYG9830T1067 Symb: 3CP

I figured that this is with quite a lot of Coorps so. What does it explaination for that? Which one should i buy?

Comment: Yes, but also no. What would be the common stock of Xiaomi and how do I generally figure this out?

Comment: KYG9830T1067 appears to be its listing in Hong Kong. US98421U1088 appears to be an unsponsored ADR (1 ADS: 5 ordinary) traded on the OTC Pink market in the US. I did not write this as an answer because I have not done the necessary research.